# NetworkAccessManager in Qthread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, threadpool, qthread

I am developing an application which contains simple data communication between server and client in QT4.7.

I need to background hidden synchronization from the client side.

So I have decided to use the ***Qthread*** for that.

But I am getting an error that i can not pass ***QnetwrokAccessManager*** Object to the Thread.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you need threads? Qt's network stuff works asynchronously itself.

Answer (score 0):

As [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) say

> QNetworkAccessManager has an asynchronous API.

Thus you do not need to use threads at all. The only thing you need is to evaluate communication with your QNetworkAccessManager via signals/slots.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended, but you can use `qnam->moveToThread` method. QNetworkAccessManager must be executed only in one thread. I really don't understand, why you need to pass it somewhere.

In most cases `QNetworkAccessManager` should be executed in main thread, but if you need to process a lot of network events that does not modify GUI (and should not weighted GUI thread)- you may move/create `QNetworkAccessManager` to/in another thread.

Could you edit your question to be more clear (some code samples, what you are trying to do)?